# Empty block {} transforms to struct

Tags: c, struct

I am reading some C language codes(seems written according to C11) about compiler principle got from Github,links below.

https://github.com/rui314/8cc

I get some codes begin from main.c like:

Firstly,a struct:

`typedef struct {
    void **body;
    int len;
    int nalloc;
} Vector;`

and then a macro:

`#define EMPTY_VECTOR ((Vector){})`

and last:

`static Vector *cond_incl_stack = &EMPTY_VECTOR;`

My question is that if it is possible to transform a empty block to a struct and assigned to a pointer and I write some codes to test:

`Vector v=(Vector){};
 Vector a[3]={};`

and there is no compliant in Qt5

Comment: What confused me is that after that the pointer `static Vector *cond_incl_stack = &EMPTY_VECTOR;` is used in the following codes like `if(cond_inc_stack->len>=8)`.

Comment: `(Vector){}` is ill-formed in Standard C. It might be a compiler extension with the same effect as `(Vector){0}`. Try compiling with `-std=c11 -pedantic` and see if the compiler gives a message.

Answer (score 5):

An empty initializer list is not allowed in any version of C.

I believe this is a GNU non-standard extension. Don't use it. If you want the standard equivalent, initialize at least one of the elements:

```
Vector v = {0};
```

Same goes for compound literals:

```
Vector v = (Vector){0};
```

---

Edit: quote from the standard:

```
(6.7.9) initializer-list:
        designationopt initializer
        initializer-list , designationopt initializer
```

Comment: Could you please mention the quote from standard saying not to use empty brace initializer?

Comment: Actually I was looking for if there it is mentioned explicitly :)

Comment: @haccks Not as far as I can tell, but they don't need to, the quoted "syntax goo" is just as normative.